# Markov dynamic programming recursion

Tags: markov-chains, linear-programming

I'm learning Markov dynamic programming problem and it is said that we must use backward recursion to solve MDP problems. 
My thought is that since in a Markov process, the only existing dependence is that the next stage (n-1 stages to go) depends on the current stage (n stages to go) and not the other way around. Is this the reason? But isn't forward recursion also implemented based on this kind of dependence? 
Could anyone help me to understand why we must use backward? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Markov decision process* involves computing some quantity of the
form
$$
v^N(i)\equiv\sup_{\pi}\mathbb{E}^{(i)}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{N}\underbrace{\frac{1}{\left(1+\rho\right)^{n}}}_{\text{discount}}u(X_{n}^{\pi})\right]
$$
where $(X_{n}^{\pi})_{n\geq0}$ is a controlled, time-homogeneous, Markov chain taking values in a finite state space $\mathcal{S}=\{1,\ldots,M\}$. $\mathbb{E}^{(i)}$ is the expectation conditional on $X_{0}=i$, where $i\in\mathcal{S}$. Note that $N$ is the number of timesteps until the "game" is over.

Without worrying too much about regularity, note that
\begin{align*}
v^N(i) & \equiv\sup_{\pi}\left\{ u(X_{0})+\frac{1}{1+\rho}\mathbb{E}^{(i)}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\left(1+\rho\right)^{n-1}}u(X_{n}^{\pi})\right]\right\} \\
 & =\sup_{\pi}\left\{ u(X_{0})+\frac{1}{1+\rho}\mathbb{E}^{(i)}\left[v^{N-1}(X_{1}^{\pi})\right]\right\} \\
 & =\sup_{\pi}\left\{ u(i)+\frac{1}{1+\rho}\sum_{j}p_{ij}(\pi)v^{N-1}(j)\right\} 
\end{align*}
where $p_{ij}(\pi)$ is the probability that a transition from state $i$ to $j$ occurs.

> In the second equality above, we have related the value of
>   $v^N$ to that of $v^{N-1}$. The dynamic programming algorithm thus involves computing $v^0,v^1,v^2,\ldots$ in that order. This is why it is referred to as *backwards* (recall that $v^N$ is the value assuming there are $N$ steps remaining).

In fact, going a bit further, we can write the above equation in the
vector form
$$
\mathbf{v}^{N}=\sup_{\pi}\left\{ \frac{P(\pi)}{1+\rho}\mathbf{v}^{N-1}+\mathbf{u}\right\}
$$
where $P(\pi)$ is the matrix with coefficients $p_{ij}(\pi)$, and
the supremum is to be interpreted row-wise.

---

The steady-state case ($N=\infty$) is slightly more complicated. In the steady-state case, $\mathbf{v}^N=\mathbf{v}^{N-1}$, and the above equation becomes (letting $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}^N$)
$$
0=\sup_{\pi}\left\{ \left(\frac{P(\pi)}{1+\rho}-I\right)\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u}\right\}.
$$
This equation can be solved by Howard's policy iteration. For details, see *Section 2* (namely, *Proposition 2.2*) in [1].

---

[1] P. Azimzadeh, P. A. Forsyth, "Weakly chained matrices, policy iteration, and impulse control", In arXiv preprint [arXiv:1510.03928](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03928.pdf), 2015.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I'm confused about your second equation, aren't we looking for an optimal route to get the largest reward? Then basically my question is why we cannot use forward recursion just like normal dynamic programming problem? And how could we decide whether a forward or backward recursion is proper for a dynamic programming problem?

Comment: I have edited my answer to use the finite-horizon $N<\infty$. This might make things more clear. "Forward" and "backward" are simply intuitive concepts; you should always use induction to move initial data to where you want it to go. In the above example, we know $v^0$ (the terminal value), so we should use it to compute $v^1$, and so forth.

Comment: Thank you. So can I say when there are terminal rewards, backward recursion should be used?

Comment: Correct. I think it's important to also understand that "backwards" and "forwards" are simply intuitive notions. Under the hood, it's all induction.

Comment: Yes I understand now. Thank you! :-)